# Ошибка в написании метода класса - нужна помощь

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, я новичок в PHP, изучаю классы и объекты. Надо создать класс товара и категории товаров. Для категорий задать методы добавления товара в категорию, метод вывода категории со всеми товарами на экран, и метод вывода всех категорий со всеми товарами.

Есть классы

**good.class.php**

```
class good{
 var $good_name;

var $price;

var $good_value; //для распределения по категориям

function setGood ($good_name, $price, $value) {

    $this->good_name = $good_name;
    $this->price = $price;
    $this->good_value = $value;
}

}
```

**category.class.php**

```
include_once 'good.php';

class category {

    var $cat_id;
    var $cat_name;

function setCategoryGood($good_name) {

        if ($good_value=$cat_name) {
            $category = array("$good_name"=>"$price");
        }
    }

    }

    function displayCategory($cat_name){
        $this->cat_name=$cat_name;
            foreach ($category as $good_name=>$price) {
            echo $good_name." - ".$price;
        }

    function displayAllCategory(){
        $all_category = array("$cat_name" => "$category");
        foreach ($all_category as $cat_name => "$category") {
            foreach ($category as $good_name => $price) {
                echo  $cat_name.'</br>
                <li>$good_name - $price</li>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once('good.php');

require_once('category.php');


$good1 = new good();

$good1->setGood ('rose', '10$', 'flower');

$cat1 = new category();

$cat1 ->cat_name='flower';

$cat1->setCategoryGood('flower');

$cat1->displayCategory('flower');
```

Этот код не работает :) Fatal error: Call to undefined method category::displayCategory() 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где в нем ошибки?

Answer (score 3):

Лишняя скобка после метода setCategoryGood, отсуствие закрывающей скобки перед displayAllCategory, вот так правильно:

```
include_once 'good.php';

class category {
    var $cat_id;
    var $cat_name;

    function setCategoryGood($good_name) {
        if ($good_value==$this->cat_name) {
            $category=array($good_name=>$price);
        }
    }

    function displayCategory($cat_name){
        $this->cat_name=$cat_name;
         foreach ($category as $good_name=>$price) {
            echo $good_name." - ".$price;
        }
    }

    function displayAllCategory(){
        $all_category = array($cat_name => $category);
        foreach ($all_category as $cat_name => $category) {
            foreach ($category as $good_name => $price) {
                echo  $cat_name."</br><li>$good_name - $price</li>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Елена, Ваш код полон ошибок. Откуда вы в методе setCategoryGood в строчке

```
$category=array($good_name=>$price);
```

берете price? Может его туда нужно передавать через параметр?

У вас были проблемы в том, что вы в двойные кавычки заключаете переменные, так делать не нужно. А также в if вместо двух равно, которые используются для сравнения, использовали одно =, которое служит для присваивания и следовательно и у вас условие всегда будет true.

Также строка

```
</br><li>$good_name - $price</li>
```

У Вас была в одинарных кавычках, а это значит что перменные внутри не будут обрабатываться интерпретатором.

Вы также создали класс good, но нигде его не использовали.

**Правильное решение по вашей задаче**

```
<?php

class Good {

    protected $name;
    protected $price;

    public function __construct($name, $price) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }
}

class Category {

    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $goods;

    public function __construct($id, $name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $name;
        $this->goods = [];
    }

    public function add(Good $good) {
        $this->goods[] = $good;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function show() {
        foreach ($this->goods as $good) {
            echo $good->getName()."-".$good->getPrice()."<br>";
        }
    }
}

Class Categories {

    protected $categories;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->categories = [];
    }

    public function add(Category $category) {
        $this->categories[] = $category;
    }

    public function show() {
        foreach ($this->categories as $category) {
            echo "Название категории:".$category->getName()."<br>";
            echo "Список товаров: <br>";
            $category->show();
            echo "<br><br>";
        }
    }

}

$category = new Category("flowers", 1);
$category->add(new Good("flower", 15));
$category->add(new Good("flower", 25));
$category->add(new Good("flower", 32));

$categories = new Categories();
$categories->add($category);

$categories->show();
```

Вывод будет:

```
Название категории:1
Список товаров:
flower-15
flower-25
flower-32
```

Написал на основе вашей задачи пример, чтобы Вам было легко разобраться в ООП.

У нас есть 3 класса:

1. **Good** - класс для товара
2. **Category** - класс для категории
3. **Categories** - класс для категорий

Мы имеем класс Good, который в себе имеет свойства price и name, это как в реальной жизни: товар имеет свойства. Далее, у нас есть класс категории, который имеет свойства id и name. Данные свойства скрыты для изменения из вне, и для их получения необходимо пользоваться функциями getName, getId и т.д, которые определенны в классе.

То есть, вы можете создать экземпляр класса и вывести его имя:

```
$good = new Good("flower", 15)
echo $good->getName(); //выведет flower
```

Также мы имеем внутри Category массив, который будет хранить все товары категории, и будем в него добавлять товары с помощью метода add, а добавлять будем только экземпляры класса Good. Естественно, чтобы вывести все товары из категории нужно просто перебрать массив и обратиться к методам getName и getPrice класса Good, которые у нас добавлены, этим занимается метод show(). Тоесть, чтобы вывести все товары категории, нужно их туда добавить и вызвать метод show().

```
$good = new Good("flower", 15); //создаем товар flower с ценой 15
$category = new Category("flowers", 1); //создаем категорию с названием flowers и id = 1
$category->add($good); //добавляем товар в категорию
$category->show();  //выводим все товары
```

Далее, мы имеем класс Categories, который содержит в себе экземпляры класса Category, про простому массив категорий и метод для вывода show(), метод по сути обращается просто к методам класса category getName и show() чтобы вывести информацию по категории.

```
 $good = new Good("flower", 15); //создаем товар flower с ценой 15
    $category = new Category("flowers", 1); //создаем категорию с названием flowers и id = 1
    $category->add($good); //добавляем товар в категорию
    $categories = new Categories(); //Создаем обьект категорий
    $categories->add($category); //Добавляем категорию
    $categories->show(); //Делаем вывод всех товаров и категорий
```

Надеюсь у Вас немного теперь появилось понимание ООП.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там еще и if ($good_value=$cat_name) стояло в функции setCategoryGood

Comment: `Откуда вы в методе setCategoryGood в строчке берете price?` - потому что она не знает, что `include_once 'good.php'` не добавляет поля одного класса в другой)

Comment: @Firepro  спасибо!  да, переменные $price и $good_name из файла good.php :) Вы не подскажете, как их правильно добавить в catalog.php?

Comment: @Elena решите проблему с переменной price и используйте класс good в полной степени. Передавайте его в функции и используйте, иначе зачем он Вам нужен? :)

Comment: @Firepro так в том и проблема, что я не могу разобраться как правильно передать переменные из класса good в класс category :)

Comment: @Elena написал корректное решение вашей задачи в стиле ООП в своем ответе (обновил ответ), надеюсь это поможет Вам разобраться в том, как правильно передавать переменные и писать программы.